# How do I get IEventBroker injected into an e4 OSGI service component

Tags: components, osgi, rcp, e4

I am trying to get IEventBroker injected into my code to send out notifications.

Everything else works but eventBroker never gets injected. I do not get any compile time errors.

It just comes up null when the code is executed.

I've trimmed the code because it wouldn't let me submit it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```java
package com.test.services.internal;

imports ...

@Component
public class EnvironmentServiceImpl implements IEnvironmentService {

    @Inject
    private IEventBroker eventBroker;

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Activate
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void activateComponent() {

        getAll(environments -> {
            if (environments.isEmpty()) {
                List<Environment> initialModel = getMockEnvironments();
                initialModel.forEach(this::save);
            }
        });
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivateComponent() {

    }

    @Override
    public void getAll(Consumer<List<Environment>> taskConsumer) {

        eventBroker.post(EnvironmentEventConstants.TOPIC_ENVIRONMENT_LOADED,
                    createEventData(EnvironmentEventConstants.TOPIC_ENVIRONMENT_LOADED, updateEnvironment.getId()));
    }

    private Map<String, String> createEventData(String topic, String environmentId) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Service components are not injected, you need to use a Context Function for that - https://toedter.com/2010/06/28/eclipse-4-0-dependency-injection-and-osgi-declarative-services/

Comment: I did create a context function. However, the Activate method in the service implementation class is not being called. I started down the Reference path to get MApplication. Is that a good idea?

Comment: The class you create in the context function with ContextInjectionFactory.make is just a POJO, not a service.